# Cannot get rounded corners on a table

Tags: html

I have a flash website with an ugly form (constructed via a table) on it.  (I need to use flash because I am using one of those template sites.)

I am trying to round the top corners of the header (title area) and the bottom corners of the footer (submit area) that works with IE too.

I have seen several websites describing how to round textboxes (or text areas) but none for tables except with graphics via photoshop.  I have tried to do that, but it is apparently above my skill level because it is not working!

I have had a little luck with generateit.net which provides an html snippet.  But, it is also designed for a textbox and I am getting erratic results.

I would post my webpage but I have not yet published it.  I can see it on my account at the template website.  Trust me, though.  They are erratic.  Can anyone point me to a website that can help me with html code for a table with rounded edges (without graphics)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Show some of the HTML code that you have that doesn't work, somebody can certainly point you in the right direction.

Comment: can you fix this wall of text issue? you know, with paragraph and thing like that

Comment: I don't think you *can* style `table`, or its child, elements with rounded corners (certainly not in Chrome 8/Ubuntu 10.10 in which I've specified `border-radius: 1em;` on *every* valid table element (`table`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `th` and `td`) that I could think of ([JS Fiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zRVjs/)). Background-images might be a possibility?

Comment: I too suspect what @David says. Maybe wrap a `div` with rounded corners around it?

Comment: @Pekka, nice idea...that works: [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zRVjs/1/); your idea, I'll happily pass the credit to you on this one =D

Comment: @David nice work! Feel free to post it as an answer. The only downside with this is that it doesn't work in IE 8 (But I'm not up to speed about what workarounds exist for that, if any)

Answer (score 3):

Because this question's sat, 'unanswered<sup>1</sup>,' for a while I thought I'd expand my comments as an answer:

The `table` element, and its valid child elements (`thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `th` and `td`), presumably due to the inherent nature of a table (though I have no reference to support, or explain, that assumption) refuse to accept or apply the `border-radius` property: [JS Fiddle demo, tested in Chrome 8.x and Firefox 3.6.x on Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zRVjs/).

To get around this, as @Pekka suggests, it's possible to wrap the table in a `div` and apply `border-radius` to *that*, along with `overflow: hidden;` to prevent the corners of the `table` appearing outside of the curved borders of the `div` itself.

In the demo I put together for this I used a heavier border for the containing `div` to reduce the antialiasing artefacts where the curved border meets the `table` border, but, obviously, used the same colour for both elements.

#### html:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Name</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Family</th>
                <th>First</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Age information from Wikipedia</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Freeman</td>
                <td>Martin</td>
                <td>39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Freeman</td>
                <td>Morgan</td>
                <td>73</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### css:

```
#container {
    border-radius: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    min-width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

th {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zRVjs/2/).

---

1. Outside of those posted in the comments to the question (above).